# React.js FixedDataTable - Row heights are not evaluated when table is re-rendered - scrollbar is missing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fixed-data-table

I have dynamic data in my table. The amount of data in a cell may change. I have implemented a `rowHeightGetter` method to calculate the height of a row. When I add content to a cell and rerender my table, the content appears and the cell is larger, but if the additional content caused overflow, scrollbars do not show up. Please see the jsfiddle and click on a row. You'll see that you can no longer access the bottom row of the table until you click a second time.

https://jsfiddle.net/3cooper/ed7Ltc6o/1/

It appears that `_calculateState()` is not getting the actual row heights from the rowHeightGetter methods when it calls

```
var scrollContentHeight = this._scrollHelper.getContentHeight()
```

At this point it is getting the height of the rows by checking the rowHeight property on the table. I see in `_calculateState()` there are other calls that eventually call `this._scrollHelper._updateHeightsInViewport()` to properly get the height. Should this be done again. Just really started looking into this today - so I could be missing something obvious. Thanks.

Is there a better way to handle this?

Update:

Also, I notice that once a scrollbar appears so that the contents can scroll, if you click a row again, the table with shift down but the scrollbar will not adjust. Then once you start to scroll up the scroll jumps to the correct position and allows you to scroll the entire table correctly.